# Accessing lazy loaded property in NHibernate ASP.NET MVC3 Razor code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, razor, lazy-loading

I have a Post class:

```
public class Post
{
    ...
    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In mappings I set Comments as a ManyToOne reference. As we know by default it's set as lazy loaded.

In my Razor view script I want to check if post has any comment and if so, add a button that calls an action to get comments for that post via ajax and show them, by injecting html.
When I try to invoke something on Post.Comments in Razor (like Model.Comments.Count()) I recieve an exception saying that Session is not present. I know why that happens - because the lazy loading.
My question is how to handle these kind of situations? What are the 'best practices'?

Two solutions comes to my mind:
1) Set Comments as not lazy loaded - not ok since I get comments via ajax later and for this time I need only the Count of comments 
2) Create a ViewModel class that contains information if post has comments or pass this via ViewBag.

What are your suggestions on this?

Thanks,
Bartek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would go with option 2.

Create a ViewModel, include a property like `HasComments` and use that in your view instead of trying to evaluate `Model.Comments.Count()`.

Comment: IMHO this solution is the one you should go for. When at action method produce a ViewModel which consists of all database specific information. That ViewModel should be used by the Razor to generate the desired HTML - and this w\o any calls to a database.

Answer (score 1):

Why is your session ending so early?

You should keep it open still during render, for times like that.

Comment: I use: `using(session) { (...) return ViewModel(...); }` so session should be active as using block has not ended yet. But it doesn't work. Actually I would not prefer to use complex logic and db operations from view. I agree with @John Allers and @Julian S that I should go with option.

Comment: Actually your just returning a ViewResult instance, and when that method returns (after the using block has disposed) the view is generated, hence your error.